# How to integrate Image recognition with website?

Tags: web, machine-learning, tensorflow, image-recognition

I am a web designer, and I am thinking of building a **face recognition application** using machine learning concept. I want to build a website where people will upload photos (with Face) and the website will compare the face in image with the database of images and give the matches found from it. I want to know how to build such face recognition system and **how to integrate it with website.**
And will TensorFlow will be involved?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on whether your web application (mainly the GUI portion) will be using the same platform or computer languages as the one for the machine learning portion. As you have already mentioned TensorFlow, if your backend (face recognition system) is based on Python and TensorFlow (most likely and also recommended), while your frontend might be using J2EE, PHP, ASP.NET, you need a way to communicate between the two subsystems. An easy way is jut to call the command from the GUI part (running the backend as a command); while an open architecture would be to establish a web service: you develop a web service as an interface for your GUI to call. This way, your frontend can be changed to any platform as you prefer in the future. You can even publish your web service to others if you really created a very powerful system one day.